# tee:read error:permission denied

Tags: linux, nfs

I am running some process on nfs system and I am storing output of the process to some file using tee command.
But I am getting error "**tee:read error:permission denied**".
Any clue when this error can occur ?

Comment: perhaps sounds like squash_root is blocking your access to that file

Comment: Hi Jasen, what is squash_root ? One more input this error is not consistent.Some time same process runs successfully without throwing any error.

Comment: squash_root a a nfs mount option, it makes root like nobody, breaks all kinds of stuff,  but if it's intermittent the problem is probably something else.